# Oracle VirtualBox VM network not working

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am attempting to set up a VM using VirtualBox. I am hosting on Windows 10 and want to set up a CentOS vm. I have a VM running but have had problems getting network connectivity with it. I have no experience with VirtualBox and it has been a long time since I worked on Linux. Any ideas on what I need to do to correct this? Are there some steps I need to take during the creation of the image?

Image is : CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1708.iso
VirtualBox : Version 5.1.28 r117968 (Qt5.6.2)

When I try to ping anything I get " connection the Network is unreachable

Comment: Not sure why this got a down vote. Did I not explain the issue well enough?

Answer (score 0):

The very best thing you should do is running the following command:

```
ifconfig -a
```

Then, If you have an interface listed (not just 'lo'), you can do that:

```
# cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ 
# sed -i -e 's@^ONBOOT="no@ONBOOT="yes@' ifcfg-{{network_device}}
```

replace {{network_device}} for your default network_device (from `ifconfig-a` command).

Then restart and it should connect.

Comment: I this version of CentOS does not appear to have ifconfig. It appears to have been replaced with IP? What would be the equivalent set of commands in : CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1708?

Comment: It seems in CentOS-7 is `ip addr`